# C++: can you force the access to a private member of a class?

Tags: c++

Basically I am using a library and I don't want to redefine its classes so I can't change the member I am interested in to Public. Can you force the compiler ?

Comment: I believe that defeats the intent of that member being private. What is the context in which you are trying to do this?

Comment: You could. But that's not what member access control was invented for. Instead you will learn how to do it with your libraries public methods.

Comment: Just don't, that's a horrible idea.

Comment: If that member was meant to be changed manually, I'm sure there is an interface in that library that allows you to change it. Otherwise, you're just asking for troubles.